# How can I send a gnome desktop notification from a .desktop app launcher?

Tags: gnome, bash, scripts, launcher, .desktop

I'm running a shell script inside a gnome .desktop file to backup my disk to an external disk, running as root:

```
Exec:gksu /home/nhiton/bin/sync_home_to_alpha.bash
```

However, I can't seem to do anything to learn if the script exited successfully.  I have tried the following:

1. Adding a sleep at the end of the script so I have some time to see the result, just exits immediately
2. I tried running a different script to split out the gksu portion from the notify-send:

.

```
Exec:/home/nhilton/bin/test_sync.bash

# test_sync.bash
gksu sync_home_to_alpha.bash

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    notify-send "SUCCESS"
else
    notify-send "FAILURE"
fi
```

It seems no combination will allow me to signal the exit status of the script.

Help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the exec line:

```
Exec=bash -c "/home/nhilton/bin/test_sync.bash && notify-send Success || notify-send Fail"
```

Whole point is that `if` and `&&` constructs are shell syntax,  so you actually need a shell there to understand them. Hence the use of `bash -c`

Mind the single and double quotes and double check other parameters in .desktop file

Comment: Hmm, seems to work as expected from the command line: "gtk-launch sync_home_to_alpha.desktop" but I get no output or notification or terminal window when I launch using the gnome activities window.

Comment: @Nick  I've seen a couple questions lately where users say they have issues  opening .desktop files from gnome activities menu. Maybe gnome developers changed something, but otherwise I've no clue. Where do you store the file ? Try setting executable bit on it with `chmod +x`

Comment: turns out it was the quotes, when I used " around everything it works: bash -c "..."

Comment: @Nick No, quotes were OK. I had a stray backtick at the end, I just noticed. But double quotes in this case will do, too. Usually single quotes are preferred on command line to avoid the calling shell replacing variables